# C++, code to write the binary form of an integer after the decimal point

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

What I want is to take in an integer, and convert it to binary in a method as close to the method shown in the below code. However, I want to convert the number to binary as if it were after a decimal point. So if I got 625 as input then I would want it converted into 101.

Given the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int decTobinary(int);

int main(){
    cout << "Enter a number = ";
    int num;
    cin >> num; 
    int answer = decTobinary(num);
    cout << "answer: " << answer << endl"
    return 0;
}
int decTobinary(int x) {
    if (x==0)
    return 0;
    return 10 * decTobinary(x/2) + x % 2;
}
```

Comment: 101 in binary is 5, or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: What you really want is to convert 0.625 (base-10) to 0.101 (base-2), correct?

Comment: @Borgleader it's probably my fault for being unclear. 101 is 5 in binary but 0.101 would represent .625, so I want to take the integer and convert it to binary as if it were after a decimal point, and for the binary to show up without the decimal point, so that's why i wrote 101 and not .101

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, but with only imagining that the "0." part is there. so converting 625 to 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked it together so it's not pretty but it gives the output you were looking for:

```
#include <iostream>

float intToDecimalPoint(float f)
{
    if((f / 10.0f) <= 1.0f)
        return f/10.0f;
    else
        return intToDecimalPoint(f/10.0f);
}

void decTobinary(int x)
{
    if (x==0)
        return;

    float decimalPoint = intToDecimalPoint(float(x));
    if(decimalPoint*2.0f >= 1.0f)
    {
        std::cout << 1;
        int newX = int((decimalPoint*2.0f - 1.0f)*(float(x)/decimalPoint));
        return decTobinary(newX);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << 0;
        decTobinary(x*2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number = ";
    int num;
    std::cin >> num; 
    std::cout << "answer: ";
    decTobinary(num);
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Algo is from [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130412173826AAow85E). My solution is not perfect due to floating point imprecision but it should work for most cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int GetNumberOfDigits (int i)
{
    return i > 0 ? (int) log10 ((double) i) + 1 : 1;
};

void function(int number, vector<int> &convert)    {
    double remainder = number/pow(10,GetNumberOfDigits(number));
    do
    {
        remainder = remainder*2;
        convert.push_back(int(remainder));
        remainder = remainder - int(remainder);
    }
    while(remainder != 0);
};

int main()  {
    vector<int> solution;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter number: ";
    cin>>n;
    function (n, solution);
    for(int index = 0; index < solution.size(); index++) std::cout<<solution[index];
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Archive for the ‘C Programming’ Category](http://www.programmingclub.in/category/c-programming/)
http://www.programmingclub.in/category/c-programming/

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

void main()

{

  int a[10],n,i,j=0;

  printf(“Enter the Number: “);

  scanf(“%d”,&n);

  while(n>0)

  {

             i=n%2;

             a[j++]=i;

             n=n/2;

            }

  j–;

  printf(“\nBinary form is: \n”);

  while(j>=0)

  {

             printf(“%d”,a[j]);

             j–;

            }

            getch();

  }
```